# Building the shared folder support module....fail!

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

I want to share a folder between my host windows7 and guest Ubuntu but whenever I select add guest additions I get the following error:

> Unable to mount the CD/DVD image
>   C:\PROGRA~1\Oracle\VIRTUA~1\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso on the machine
>   Ubuntu. Would you like to force mounting of this medium?
>
> Could not unmount the currently mounted media/drive
>   (VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED).

What should I do?

I got the following message on the terminal: ... Building the main guest additions module...done! Building the shared folder support module....fail!

Atleast tell me how I can enable copy and paste between the host and guest. I have changed the settings to bidirectional but still the copy/paste is not working

Comment: Go to CD Drive in guest operating system(in this case ubuntu). and follow the instructions http://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-ubuntu/

Comment: I got the following message on the terminal:


...



Building the main guest additions module...done!
Building the shared folder support module....fail!